# Does nginx line ordering within a location matters?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Specifically I have the following location:

```
location / {
    root ...;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    ....
    add_header ....
    server_tokens off;
    # Does the order of the next 2 lines matter?
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass django;
  }
```

I'm wondering if the order of the lines in it matters. And specifically about the 2 last lines.

Comment: The order of the last two lines should not be significant. Are you encountering a problem? If so, what is in the file `uwsgi_params`?

Comment: I'm not encountering a problem. Just learning. Couldn't find anywhere mentioning this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any documentation that answered the question "does the order of directives in a location block matter?". However, through studying the examples in the [Nginx uwsgi module document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html), as listed below:

```
location / {
    include    uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass localhost:9000;
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass        backend;
    uwsgi_cache       cache_zone;
    uwsgi_cache_key   $uri;
    uwsgi_cache_purge $purge_method;
}

location /fetch/ {
    internal;

    uwsgi_pass         backend:9000;
    ...

    uwsgi_store        on;
    uwsgi_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
    uwsgi_temp_path    /data/temp;

    alias              /data/www/;
}
```

I guess that the order of the `uwsgi_pass` directive and other `uwsgi_param` directives inside the `uwsgi_params` file is not important. As you see, the `uwsgi_pass` directive can be at the beginning, the middle, or the end of a block.

Furthermore, in the article that explains [how to use NGINX as an application gateway with uWSGI and Django](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/app-gateway-uwsgi-django/), the `uwsgi_pass` directive can also lie between `uwsgi_param` directives, as follows:

```
location /main {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass django;
    uwsgi_param Host $host;
    uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
}
```

Based on my experience when setting up PHP websites with FastCGI, the order of the directives doesn't matter. However, *if you declare the same directive more than once inside a block, the last declared directive will take effect*.